# Генерация документации для нескольких проектов

Tags: .net, .net-core, документация

Есть N кол-во репозиториев .NET Core проектов, которые по итогу публикуются в локальный Nuget, таким образом они между друг другом и связаны.

Каким образом можно создать общую документацию для всех этих N репозиториев?

Пробовал что-то типа [SourceBrowser](https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/SourceBrowser), но оно какое-то всё топорное, HtmlGenerator на net framework вообще, в конечном итоге так и не понял как это адекватно использовать это для моей задачи.

Document!X, к сожалению, платный, что не особо подходит

Comment: SourceBrowser это же для исходников, а не документации. Вам документация то какая нужна, сайт с перечнем API и описаниями к ним на основе XML-комментариев?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight для API Swagger, а мне нужно что-то типа MSDN от майкрософта, когда по названию класса/метода и пр. можно посмотреть и код, и описание с комментариями

Comment: Для самой генерации сайта можно использовать какой-нибудь [docfx](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx). Но особых инструментов, чтобы генерировать из нескольких репозиториев единую документацию, в нем нету. Можно в docfx.json ссылаться на файлы из разных репозиториев, но тогда нужно сделать какой-то скрипт, который в один каталог будет их клонировать.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight вот docfx тоже странно как-то выглядит, если честно, если больше вариантов не будет, то буду думать на счет docfx

Comment: docfx используется в новом сайте документации Microsoft Learn, который теперь вместо MSDN, поэтому это наиболее близко к тому, что вам нужно. Хотя сам шаблон с Microsoft Learn закрытый, поэтому создать сайт, который выглядит так же, не получится.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight понял, спасибо, тогда будем пробовать docfx сначала